# Doing repeatedly $remove request to the server with AngularJs gives a 500

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

When doing $remove request rapidly the server (express) will give an 500 error. Is there a way to chain $remove requests to the server or do something else to make it work?

This is my controller code:

```
$scope.removeaccounts = function(account){
var self = this;
account.$remove();
$scope.accounts.splice(self.userId, 1);
};
```

Comment: What's happening on the server that causes the 500 error? Isn't this a problem that should be fixed on the server?

Comment: Account is and object with a resource attribute of remove. I'll console.log the id's on both server and client to see if there are duplicated delete actions. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: With attribute I meant method.